# How to declare controller action method return type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, return-type, actionresult

I understand `ActionResult` is the base class for `RedirectResult` class so essentially functionality for the code below is the same.

Is there an advantage to explicitly specify the appropriate result class as a return type as opposed to the base class?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("Home/Contact");
}

public RedirectResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("Home/Contact");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need redirect quickly to another action without lost any data and this action is in the same controller , call the action as a method:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Contact();
}
public IActionResult Contact()
{
   ....
}
```

which one from another redirections methods is better is an opinion-based question and is not allowed by SO policy